# testing nginx and alpine connection with hello world

Tags: linux, centos, kubernetes, yaml, kubectl

I have a kubernetes pod that consists on 1 nginx container and 1 alpine container. I want to test with hello world to be sure I can curl alpine from nginx. Can someone tell me how I could best test that?

Would I need to copy a file from the host to the pod, and how would I best do that if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set up the nginx, set it up with a service in front of it and then you should be able to use curl from an interactive session on that alpine container, either as a dynamic pod that you run and kill, or using `exec` to open a session and do what you want.

There's [a walk-through on how to run nginx as a stateless application using a deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-stateless-application-deployment/) that you can follow for the first part of this, and then the docs on [kubernetes services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) should give you a good idea on how to form up that service. You could also take a shortcut to make this service and simply use the command:

`kubectl expose deployment nginx-deployment --port=80`

which will match to that example deployment in the docs.

Once that service is created, it'll have [a DNS entry that will be visible to other pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) in that cluster. You can vet that pretty easily by using `nslookup` from the same Alpine container. You can run a quick'n'dirty interactive alpine container with:

`kubectl run -it alpine-interactive --image=alpine -- sh`

And then:

`nslookup nginx-deployment.default`

and

`curl nginx-deployment.default` should get you where you want.

(I wrote this up without an environment to double check, but hopefully it's reasonably close to accurate)